# duplicate sift keypoints in a single image

Tags: opencv, duplicates, sift

i'm using opencv2.3.1 to detect SIFT keypoints in an image. But i find that in the detection result, there are duplicate points. i.e., there are two keypoints with the same coordinates(in pixel), but their corresponding descriptors are very different. The following code shows the SIFT extraction procedure. I think people should be familiar with the used "box.png". So anyone who is interested can try the following code and see if you have the same problem with me.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include <iostream>
int main( )
{
cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector = cv::FeatureDetector::create( "SIFT" );
cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> extractor = cv::DescriptorExtractor::create("SIFT" );
cv::Mat im = cv::imread("box.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR );
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
cv::Mat descriptors;
detector->detect( im, keypoints);
extractor->compute( im,keypoints,descriptors);
int duplicateNum = 0;
for (int i=0;i<keypoints.size();i++)
{
    for (int j=i+1;j<keypoints.size();j++)
    {
        float dist = abs((keypoints[i].pt.x-keypoints[j].pt.x))+abs((keypoints[i].pt.y-keypoints[j].pt.y));
        if (dist == 0)
        {
            cv::Mat descriptorDiff = descriptors.row(i)-descriptors.row(j);
            double diffNorm = cv::norm(descriptorDiff);
            std::cout<<"keypoint "<<i<<" equal to keypoint "<<j<<" descriptor distance "<<diffNorm<<std::endl;
            duplicateNum++;
        }
    }
}
std::cout<<"Total keypoint: "<<keypoints.size()<<", duplicateNum: "<<duplicateNum<<std::endl;

return 1;
```

}

Answer (score 9):

Hope to help you understand why.

The magnitude and orientation is calculated for all pixels around the keypoint. Then, A histogram is created for this.
In this histogram, the 360 degrees of orientation are broken into 36 bins (each 10 degrees). Lets say the gradient direction at a certain point (in the “orientation collection region”) is 18.759 degrees, then it will go into the 10-19 degree bin. And the “amount” that is added to the bin is proportional to the magnitude of gradient at that point.
Once you’ve done this for all pixels around the keypoint, the histogram will have a peak at some point.

Suppose, you see the histogram peaks at 20-29 degrees. So, the keypoint is assigned orientation 3 (the third bin)

**Also, any peaks above 80% of the highest peak are converted into a new keypoint**. This new keypoint has the same location and scale as the original. But it’s orientation is equal to the other peak.

So, orientation can split up one keypoint into multiple keypoints.

Great reference about SIFT: http://aishack.in/tutorials/sift-scale-invariant-feature-transform-introduction/

Comment: Yes, that is true; but Isnt it wrong? or lets say doesnt it cause any problem for finding match in sequential images / frames?

Comment: @farzin It is right. To improve the robustness of the SIFT points, the author add this.

Comment: why it should be count as a robustness when the duplication points to same place?

Comment: @farzinparsa As you see, the orientation of a keypoint is used when the descriptor is computed, to keep the rotation invariability. Because the method used to generate keypoint orientation is relatively rough, duplicating points (more precisely speaking, keeping more points at the same position) can ease the problem as you have mores points and have more chance to get correct match without missing keypoint due to rotation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's true - openCV implementation of SIFT descriptor produces multiple descriptors for some keypoints, they differ in orientation (SIFT descriptor estimate dominant orientation of a keypoint)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem by implementing SIFT in .NET:

Same keypoints but different descriptors as shown in following:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the justification behind that?

Comment: @ vancexu: As you said "have more chance to get correct match without missing keypoint due to rotation". This is good but when it comes to match between frames that could be a potential for misleading. In some match-making algorithms for example we need atleast 5 points. what would happen if we have (lets say) 2 duplicate points? I m afraid it could be an advantegeous for such matching algorithms